# Regexp Javascript multiple matches and multiple separators

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
{!target.useremail!}-{!target.name}
```

As result I want to have the following array:

```
["useremail", "-", "name"]
```

I could also have the following string:

```
{!target.useremail!}-{!target.name} {!target.help!}{!target.thanks!}
```

This will result in:

```
["useremail", "-", "name", " ", "help", "thanks"]
```

Is it possible to archieve this with RegExp? So yes, what is the RegExp and how does it works?

With the following RegExp I am able to retrieve the first item: {!target.(.*)!}

Some remarks:

- I could have unlimited {!target.somevalues!}
- Any char(s) (except {! and !}) between the {!target.somevalue!} and another {!target.somevalue!} are accepted.

Comment: read about regexp groups and mathing

Comment: Any char(s) between the `{!target.somevalue!}` and another `{!target.somevalue!}` are accepted.` also `{!`? `{!target.name}` without `!` near `}` is an error?

Comment: {! and !} are not excepted. Corrected my question.

Comment: inside `{!!}` must be a string?

Comment: Yep, and string starts with: target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var re = /{!target\.(\w+)!?}(?=$|([^{]+)|{)/g; 
var str = '{!target.useremail!}-{!target.name} {!target.help!}{!target.thanks!}';
var m;
var arr=[];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    arr.push(m[1]);
    if (m[2])
       arr.push(m[2]);
}

console.log(arr);
["useremail", "-", "name", " ", "help", "thanks"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN9jH4/1)

Comment: `\w` not match chars like `?=)"/$&'%# ` (space, and other chars) but only **words** **underscore** and **number**

Comment: Instead of `\w+` OP can use `[^!]+` also to capture those special characters.

Comment: Yes, It only a detail... @P Griep

Answer (score 2):

```
{!(.*?)!}(?:(.+?)|){!(.*?)!}
```

You can use this.Just grab the `groups` or `captures`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/11

Answer (score 1):

```
{!target\.([^!]+)!}|([^{]+)|{/g
```

will give you every part of your search as value in matchgroup:

[demo: regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qD1eW1/1)

```
[
  {
    "match": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 9,
        "end": 18,
        "value": "useremail"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 2,
        "start": 20,
        "end": 21,
        "value": "-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 3,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 30,
        "end": 34,
        "value": "name"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 4,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 2,
        "start": 36,
        "end": 37,
        "value": " "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 5,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 46,
        "end": 50,
        "value": "help"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 6,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 61,
        "end": 67,
        "value": "thanks"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if your input is always in this style:

```
{!target.somevalue!} SOMECAHRS {!target.somevalue!}
```

what you should do is:

```
var string = '{!target.somevalue!} ffdf {!target.somevalue!}';
var regex = /\{!target\.(\w+)!\}/g;
var re = regex.exec(string);
```

now re will be an array, and the somevalue values will start in re[1] index up to re.index length